# Google ads enhanced conversion with ads api for node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-ads-api

I am trying to implement Google ads enhanced conversions. I have the option of doing it using the gtag, google tag manager or using the Ads api. However, On the Ads api I don't see any documentation related to Node Js. I am not able to figure out how I can make use of the Ads api to implement enhanced conversions with Node Js.

This is the official documentation for enhanced conversion using Ads api and i don't see anything related to Node Js

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/conversions/enhance-conversions

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? Looking myself.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides no official Node SDK currently for Google Ads API.

https://github.com/Opteo/google-ads-node is an open source node sdk. It's a bit bloated for Lambda environments, but could be fine for most people.

You'll also have to fill out a form and submit to Google for approval to use the Google Ads API. Takes 48+ hours to get approved.

Another option is Google can ping an http or sftp endpoint of yours and just get a csv file you supply of all conversions for the day. This might be a simple approach.

Let's hope Google provides an official node sdk with simple way to upload ad conversions from server.